# Is require/include, in multiple files, necessary if they are all part of the same namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

I am brand-spanking-new to the namespace concept in php.

The situation:
Multiple files in a folder and they all require/include one another for their own purposes.

If i were to place them all in the same namespace, would it still be necessary to have them require/include each other?

I did think of replacing the require/include with "use", but it seems odd to have a file in namespace foo\bar to actually 'use' foo\bar...  o_O

PS:
I am covering all my bases by asking questions while also searching the net for answers; so if you have any good sources for info/tutorials etc please feel free to share. :D

Thank you,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can get messy with all the includes/requires.  The included files on one included file, will be also included on the first one as well, with out explicitly calling it.  I would suggest, if you are using OOP approach, start out using the `__autoload()` magic method.  This will save you tons of headaches down the road when you include a file on a page that's already been included elsewhere running on that page and you get a 500 server error because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to require them, or you can use a [psr-0 compatible autoloader](https://gist.github.com/1234504)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I managed to make a solution based on your and JT Smith's answer.

Answer (score 1):

> If i were to place them all in the same namespace, would it still be necessary to have them require/include each other?

You can create a loader class for example (it's what I always do, so you only have to include/require them once, and you only have to include/require the loader class in your controller). Here is the current one I'm using:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

//include alle classes
include("classes/db.class.php");
include("classes/gastenboek.class.php");
include("classes/gebruiker.class.php");
include("classes/bericht.class.php");

session_start();

$db = new Db();

//require smarty (smarty template engine)
require('plugins/smarty/Smarty.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->setCompileDir('smarty_compile');
$smarty->setTemplateDir('templates');

//func to dump var
function dump($var)
{
    //echo ##
    echo '<pre>##';
    //print var
    print_r($var);
    //echo ##
    echo '##</pre>';
}
```

With db.class being this for example:

```
<?php
class Db
{
    //Loading Db
    public function __construct()
    {
        //do connect()
        $this->connect();
    }

    //connecting and selecting db
    private function connect()
    {
        $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pw');

        if(!$connection)
        {
            die("Kan geen verbinding maken: " . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("db", $connection);
    }

    public function DBH()
    {
        try 
        {
            $DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'user', 'pw');
            $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $DBH;
        }

        catch (PDOException $except)
        {
            echo $except->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

index.php would then only need this:

```
include("includes/loader.php");
```